# Extract chunks of text from document and write them to new text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file text file that I want to read several lines of, and write these lines out as one line to a text file. For instance, I want to start reading in lines at a certain start word, and end on a lone parenthesis. So if my start word is 'CAR' I would want to start reading until a one parenthesis with a line break is read. The start and end words are to be kept as well.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have tried pattern matching and avoiding regex but I don't think that is possible.

Code:

```
array = []
f = open('text.txt','r') as infile
w = open(r'temp2.txt', 'w') as outfile
for line in f:
    data = f.read()
    x = re.findall(r'CAR(.*?)\)(?:\\n|$)',data,re.DOTALL)
    array.append(x)
    outfile.write(x)
return array
```

What the text may look like

```
( CAR: *random info*
    *random info* - could be many lines of this
)
```

Comment: What is the question? Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Is your solution deficient in some way? Without an example of the text it will be hard to test

Comment: @wwii updated with a clear question

Comment: So, what's wrong with using regular expressions?

Comment: Nothing. Had accomplished what I am trying to do without using regex, but the file encoding i'm now dealing with (UTF-8) makes my old code useless (line breaks and such are different).

Comment: Assuming the regex pattern works, this looks good to me as is.

Comment: Edited the question a little more. I don't think the regex pattern is 100%. I want to keep the starting word, in this case 'CAR'. Also this is writing everything to one line it seems (at least in the array)

Comment: have you tried using the re.UNICODE option?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the text that you're trying to match that is causing the problem?

Comment: Edited to give an idea. Essentially want to read from 'CAR' to that last parenthesis, and write it all out as one line as opposed to many .

Comment: Is this what you're looking to do? https://regex101.com/r/oazny2/1

Comment: Yes this seems correct but my question is mainly how do I get every chunk of info like this read into one line?

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression is totally fine for these type of problems. You cannot use them when your pattern contains recursion, like get the content from the parenthesis: ((text1)(text2)).

You can use the following regular expression: `(CAR[\s\S]*?(?=\)))`

[See explanation...](https://regex101.com/r/TBUxWl/1)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your regular expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(CAR%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F(%3F%3D%5C))))

Answer (score 1):

We can match the text you're interested in using the regex pattern: `(CAR.*)\)` with flags `gms`.

Then we just have to remove the newline characters from the resulting matches and write them to a file.

```
with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
    matches = re.findall(r"(CAR.*)\)", f.read(), re.DOTALL)

with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
    for match in matches:
        f.write(" ".join(match.split('\n')))
        f.write('\n')
```

The output file looks like this:

`CAR: *random info*     *random info* - could be many lines of this`

EDIT:
updated code to put newline between matches in output file

Comment: This almost gets me there. It writes every chunk of info out to the same line, where as I want each chunk outputted on different lines